# Read Large Json in Python and take a slice as a sample

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'am dealing a really large json file (6.5GB), with my local machine, it's impossible to read it all at once. So I want to read a chunk as a testing sample and write code based on this sample before running on the entire dataset.

```
import pandas as pd


file_dir = 'D://yelp_dataset/yelp_academic_dataset_review.json'

df_review_sample = pd.read_json(file_dir, lines=True, chunksize=1000)
```

I made the following try and then `df_review_sample` become a JsonReader Object.
Is there a way to show the first chunk as a dataframe?

Comment: You need to iterate over it, it is an iterator.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if not use this iterator, is there a way to read the first 1000 lines only as a test sample?

Comment: You can always just do `next(myiterator)` to get the next value out of the iterator, in this case, a dataframe of the first 1,000 lines.

Comment: OR just process it chunk by chunk, `for df in pd.read_json(file_dir, lines=True, chunksize=1000): ...`

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue last afternoon, and I finally understood what's going on.

Using the arg lines=True and chunksize=X will create a reader that get specific number of lines.

Then you have to make a loop to display each chunk.

Here is a piece of code for you to understand :

```
import pandas as pd
import json
chunks = pd.read_json('../input/data.json', lines=True, chunksize = 10000)
for chunk in chunks:
    print(chunk)
    break
```

Chunks create a multiple of chunks according to the lenght of your json (talking in lines).
For example, I have a 100 000 lines json with X objects in it, if I do chunksize = 10 000,  I will have 10 chunks.

In the code that I gave I added a break in order to just print the first chunk but if you remove it, you will have 10 chunks one by one.